# Android: How to flip or rotate unicode character dynamically

Tags: java, android, html, kotlin, unicode

Due to lack of available unicode symbol, I'm trying to get a unicode arrow to point in the opposite direction dynamically for right-to-left languages, but it's not working. Is there a way that this can be done programmatically only?

```
textView.text = getString(R.string.app_settings) + " \u2794 " + getString(R.string.display)
```

**Current result (English)**

[image]

**Expected result (Hebrew)**

[image]

**Current result (Hebrew)**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use css transform to flip the symbol.
I would put the unicode inside a span and with javascript add a class that has the transform function in it.